# 3x2 solder pad connector

Tags: pcb, connector, soldering

What would be the best way to connect to a 3x2 group of solder pads? I created my own 3x2 connector (pardon the poor soldering), but there must be a more off the shelf way? I haven't been able to find anything. Anybody have any ideas? Images below[image: Pins to solder to]

[image: My sad attempt]

Comment: Well ... The 1st answer is to learn to solder. Sorry. But that's just awful ... I've seen many right-angle SMD connectors soldered to commercial boards with a very similar layout and it works just fine.

Comment: You go to the website of one of the larger dealers and search for right angle smd headers.  There's more versionsvof what you are looking for than you can shake a stick at.

Answer (score 3):

SMT Header

Search all the likely distributors.  They all have them.  The vertical versions are easier to solder by hand.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or a right angle SMD header.

[image]

Also available in female header types.

[image]